# Dataset of entry/exit times of vehicles in/out of a parking lot

Tags: data-request, city, traffic, parking

I am doing a study of traffic control and want to find a dataset of entries and exits of a garage or parking lot.

Then I can calculate the staying time of any car in garage or parking lot.

Example:

```
07:48 Vehicle 4569823 enters
07:54 Vehicle 0269564 enters
09:32 Vehicle 9643153 enters
11:59 Vehicle 4569823 exits
12:08 Vehicle 0269564 exits
12:55 Vehicle 4569823 enters
13:02 Vehicle 0269564 enters
18:03 Vehicle 0269564 exits
18:12 Vehicle 4569823 exits
20:18 Vehicle 9643153 exits
```

Comment: How about bike sharing? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1903/1511

Answer (score 1):

If the lot of interest is a paid lot, then you might be able to get this information from the owner.

Information from a government run lot might be possible with a Fredom of Information Act, FOIA, request.

Answer (score 0):

You can query [Open Street Map](https://www.openstreetmap.org) for amenities such as [parking or garage](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dparking) (some of them has theirs "parking_entrance" and "parking_exit") through [Overpass API](http://overpass-turbo.eu/#):

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name")];
area[name="Berlin"]->.a;
( node(area.a)[amenity=parking_entrance];
 way(area.a)[amenity=parking_entrance];
 rel(area.a)[amenity=parking_entrance]; );
out;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but here the asker is actually not looking for parking entrances and exits themselves. The asker is asking for "time of entry" and "time of exit" of vehicles in and out of the parking. I will edit the question to make that more explicit.